# What are the benefits of storing client-side files (img, css, javascript) in subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, client-side

I've noticed that all of the high traffic websites store their client-side files (img, css, javascript, etc.) either in a sub or a separate domain.

For instance, Tumblr uses a subdomain like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://secure.assets.tumblr.com/javascript/prototype_and_effects.js?024ec5b06b4396bc5c84d8624"></script>
```

Facebook uses a separate domain called `fbcdn.net` to store their css files,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y1/r/WWO883Qmw.css" />
```

Twitter also uses a separate domain called `twimg.com`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://si0.twimg.com/a/1347423426/t1/css/t1_core.bundle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

I am sure they do this because there are benefits in performance. **What are the benefits specifically?**

Also, I am building a website that people can login and logout. And each page has a few images, 3 to 4 css files, and 3 to 4 javascript files. Currently, I use the main domain to store the client-side files like this, `www.example.com/css/mypage.css`

**If I use a subdomain to store them, is there going to be any benefits in performance? (considering the fact that my website doesn't have that many client-side files)**

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Usually this is done to take advantage of CDN style caching mechanisms.  By having all static files in one place, on one server, using one hosting strategy, it makes it much simpler to manage static files like javascript, images, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not gain any performance advantages simply by using a subdomain. A subdomain dedicated to assets is generally part of a larger, performance-improving strategy.

For instance: the subdomain may actually be pointing at a physically different server than the main website, and does nothing but handle requests for static images. It may even use a different server software (say NGINX or lighttpd) that has less overhead than the traditional apache setup.

Subdomains are also commonly pointed at a CDN like Akamai or Amazon CloudFront. CDNs are companies with datacenters in different parts of the world. When you serve a static file from a computer that is geographically closer to the recipient, you greatly reduce the amount of time that file takes to reach them.

Sometimes an entirely different domain is set up to handle static requests, like facebook. That's also why the facebook domain has the letters CDN in it... because that's what it is!

Answer (score 1):

The subdomain itself does not have any benefits.  However, being on a subdomain allows the DNS system to send your request to a different server--or even a totally different set of servers (as Gunner mentioned) using a CDN style cache.  There are many fast and easy ways of hosting static content, and that can take the load off the dynamic content servers.

EDIT: I noticed that nobody noted what CDN (Content Delivery Network) stands for.